# Needing to Add a count of listings started by a person

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Previous SQL spits out a small number of userID's, how would i then go about modifying that code to then Count the number of listings they have made?

Say Joe has made 3 listings and Jeff 2 listings (Code above returned them as the only values), Which both have unique ReferenceIDs, How can i use SQL to show a count of both of their number of listings? (In the FactListings table)

Code i used to limit the users is based on location. (Below)

```
Select DISTINCT FactListings.SellerMemberID, DimensionCategoryGroups.LevelTwoCategory, DimesionMemberType.Suburb 
FROM FactListings
INNER JOIN DimensionCategoryGroups ON FactListings.CategoryID=DimensionCategoryGroups.dimCategoryGroupID
INNER JOIN DimesionMemberType ON FactListings.SellerTypeID=DimesionMemberType.dimMemberTypeID 
WHERE Suburb LIKE '%Hutt' OR Suburb LIKE 'Wellington%' OR Suburb LIKE 'Porirua';
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Select fl.SellerMemberID, COUNT(*)
FROM FactListings fl INNER JOIN
     DimensionCategoryGroups dcg ON   
     ON fl.CategoryID = dcg.dimCategoryGroupID INNER JOIN
     DimesionMemberType mt
     ON fl.SellerTypeID = mt.dimMemberTypeID 
WHERE mt.Suburb LIKE '%Hutt' OR mt.Suburb LIKE 'Wellington%' OR mt.Suburb LIKE 'Porirua'
GROUP BY fl.SellerMemberID;
```